# Excel cell values to access

Tags: excel, vba, ms-access

I am very new to access VBA.

I need to transfer values from Sheet1 of workbook Range ("C1:C10") to a new row on the access file Table1

Values from C1 has to go to first column and c2 on second and so on.

The access file is already there, so the values has to go to last row on access table

Also, is it preferable to use VBA on excel or Access for such works

Comment: When deciding whether to pull from Access or push from Excel, you need to consider which application your users are using - Access or Excel.

Comment: In order to help the community to give you the best answer possible, please read [how to ask](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) guide.

Comment: Why is Excel involved? Why not data entry directly in Access?

Answer (score 1):

You can do this from Access using VBA. Start by setting a reference to the Microsoft Excel object library (select Tools|References from within any module). Then use the following VBA code, changing the file name, table name and field names as appropriate:

```
Sub sGetExcelData()
    On Error GoTo E_Handle
    Dim db As DAO.Database
    Dim rsData As DAO.Recordset
    Dim strSQL As String
    Dim objXL As New Excel.Application
    Dim objXLBook As Excel.Workbook
    Dim objXLSheet As Excel.Worksheet
    Dim strFile As String
    Dim lngLoop1 As Long
    strFile = "C:\test\book2.xlsx"
    Set objXLBook = objXL.Workbooks.Open(strFile)
    Set objXLSheet = objXLBook.Worksheets("Sheet1")
    Set db = DBEngine(0)(0)
    strSQL = "SELECT Field1,Field2,Field3,Field4,Field5,Field6,Field7,Field8,Field9,Field10 FROM Table1 WHERE 1=2;"
    Set rsData = db.OpenRecordset(strSQL)
    With rsData
        .AddNew
        For lngLoop1 = 1 To 10
            rsData(lngLoop1 - 1) = objXLSheet.Cells(lngLoop1, 3)
        Next lngLoop1
        .Update
    End With
sExit:
    On Error Resume Next
    rsData.Close
    Set rsData = Nothing
    Set db = Nothing
    Set objXLSheet = Nothing
    objXLBook.Close SaveChanges:=False
    Set objXLBook = Nothing
    objXL.Quit
    Set objXL = Nothing
    Exit Sub
E_Handle:
    MsgBox Err.Description & vbCrLf & vbCrLf & "sGetExcelData", vbOKOnly + vbCritical, "Error: " & Err.Number
    Resume sExit
End Sub
```

A few things to note:

- By selecting the 10 fields specifically required, it makes it easy to do a loop;
- Using `WHERE 1=2` is a way of ensuring that no existing records are included on the recordset for speed;
- Fields in an Access recordset are 0-indexed, so the first field is 0, and so on.

Regards,